# How to formalize the termination of a term reduction relation in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have a term rewriting system (A, →) where A is a set and → a infix binary relation on A. Given x and y of A, x → y means that x reduces to y.

To implement some properties I simply use the definitions from `Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions` and `Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators`.

Now I want to formalize the following property :

- → is terminating, that is : there is no infinite descending chain a0 → a1 → ...

How can I achieve that in Coq ?

Comment: Have you had a look to the CoLoR library? http://color.inria.fr/

Comment: Anyways, there are several ways to formalize a termination property in Coq. 

I would personally use the definition of termination better adapted to my pen-and-paper proof, these issues are delicate.

Comment: @ejgallego I didn't know CoLoR. It looks nice ! I know that pen-and-paper proofs are more convenient for that kind of thing but I mainly wanted to try that for educational purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Showing that a rewriting relation terminates is the same thing as showing that it is well-founded. This can be encoded with an inductive predicate in Coq:

```
Inductive Acc {A} (R : A -> A -> Prop) (x: A) : Prop :=
  Acc_intro : (forall y:A, R x y -> Acc R y) -> Acc R x.

Definition well_founded {A} (R : A -> A -> Prop) :=
  forall a:A, Acc R a.
```

(This definition is essentially the same one of the `Acc` and `well_founded` predicates in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html), but I've changed the order of the relation to match the conventions used in rewriting systems.)

Given a type `A` and a relation `R` on `A`, `Acc R x` means that every sequence of `R` reductions starting from `x : A` is terminating; thus, `well_founded R` means that every sequence starting at *any* point is terminating. (`Acc` stands for "accessible".)

It might not be very clear why this definition works; first, how can we even show that `Acc R x` holds for any `x` at all? Notice that if `x` is an element does not reduce (that is, such that `R x y` never holds for any `y`), then the premise of `Acc_intro` trivially holds, and we are able to conclude `Acc R x`. For instance, this would allow us to show `Acc gt 0`. If `R` is indeed well-founded, then we can work backwards from such base cases and conclude that other elements of `A` are accessible. A formal proof of well-foundedness is more complicated than that, because it has to work generically for every `x`, but this at least shows how we could show that each element is accessible separately.

OK, so maybe we can show that `Acc R x` holds. How do we use it, then? 
With the induction and recursion principles that Coq generates for `Acc`; for instance:

```
Acc_ind : forall A (R : A -> A -> Prop) (P : A -> Prop),
   (forall x : A, (forall y : A, R x y -> P y) -> P x) ->
   forall x : A, Acc R x -> P x
```

When `R` is well-founded, this is simply the principle of well-founded induction. We can paraphrase it as follows. Suppose that we can show that `P x` holds for any `x : A` while making use of an induction hypothesis that says that `P y` holds whenever `R x y`. (Depending on the meaning of `R`, this could mean that `x` steps to `y`, or that `y` is strictly smaller than `x`, etc.) Then, `P x` holds for any `x` such that `Acc R x`.  Well-founded recursion works similarly, and intuitively expresses that a recursive definition is valid if every recursive call is performed on "smaller" elements.

Adam Chlipala's CPDT has a [chapter on general recursion](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html) that has a more comprehensive coverage of this material.

Comment: Thanks for your (great) answer ! Did you mean rather `Acc lt 0` or really `Acc gt 0` ?

Comment: I did mean gt: the definition of Acc that I gave is backwards compared to the one in the standard library.

Comment: Ok ! Is it acceptable to use the same strategy to prove the property of Strong Normalization for a variant of lambda-calculus for instance ?